# SSMS not displaying databases though able to switch database in Query window

Tags: permissions, ssms, sql-server-2016

We want to give *SELECT* permission to a *security group* for only one database. We followed the below steps:

1. We added the *security group* as login.
2. We added the *security group* as user to the database.
3. We gave *SELECT* permission on a schema to the *security group*.

Now, Security group members are able to use query window for writing queries and switch database using `USE Databasename;` command. But, still Sql Server Management Studio is not showing the database in the databases node.

The databases node just shows the system database as shown in the image below. What could be the reason for this? Unless, we give sysadmin permission, the *security group* members are not able to see the database in the databases node. They are using latest version of *SSMS* i.e., 17.

[image: Empty database node]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you removed the View Any Database permission from the Public role? If the Public role doesn't have the View Any Database permission an account has to be the owner of the DB to see it.

Comment: thanks. After executing below command, databases are visible.
    ```GRANT VIEW ANY DATABASE TO [public] ```